# Why doesn't perl care about whether I've declared my variable under stricture?

Tags: perl, scope

I spent too much time today debugging one of those insidious small mistakes.

Here is more or less what I did:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $test = new MyTest('test');
say $test->to_string for 1..3;

package MyTest;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $parm  = shift;
    return bless \$parm, $class;
}

sub to_string {
    my $self = shift;
    my $string = 'Hello!' if 0;
    $string .= $$self;
    return $string;
}
```

Notice that because of the false test, `my $string` is not evaluated. (Of course, the code I lost so much time on didn't have `if 0`!)

I realise that the compiler doesn't know that the test will be false, but shouldn't it complain that I am using a variable that may not have been declared at the following line?

Also, I would expect this to result in a run-time error, but `perl` just gives me

```
test
testtest
testtesttest
```

Why is there no error? Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: Perl::Critic will complain about the bad pattern "my $var='something' if (cond);" - useful!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`my $foo;` is suppose to be allocate a new var (kinda like `Scalar* foo = new Scalar();`), but that would be quite inefficient, so it's not implemented that way.

`my` has the compile-time effect of declaring the variable. This effectively creates it. Since it happens at compile time, it's unaffected by the `if`. As usual, the variable is scoped the block (curlies) containing it.

`my` has the run-time effect of putting a directive on the stack to replace the variable with a fresh one on scope exit. (If nothing grabbed a reference to it, it simply gets cleared instead.) This is what's being skipped.

Using a variable under different conditions than the ones under which it's declared is undefined (disallowed) behaviour.

If you're trying to create a lexically-scoped persistent variable, use

```
{
    my $x = init();

    sub foo {
        ... $x ...
    }
}
```

or

```
use feature qw( state );  # Require 5.10+

sub foo {
    state $x = init();  # init() is only called the first time foo() is called.
    ... $x ...
}
```

Comment: Er, did you mean, "[t]his is _un_affected by the `if`" ?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a tighter example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub to_string {
    my $param = shift;
    my $string = 'Hello!' if 0;
    $string .= $param;
    return $string;
}

print to_string("foo"), "\n";
print to_string("bar"), "\n";
print to_string("baz"), "\n";
```

Outputs:

```
foo
foobar
foobarbaz
```

Basically, you should never declare and conditionally initialize a variable using the syntax `my $var = $val if $cond`, as the behavior will be unexpected. [`Perl Bug 5 - my $var = val if (..) doesn't work properly`](http://davesource.com/Bugs/perl.5.html)

Instead always use the ternary in situations like that:

```
my $var = $cond ? $val : undef;
```

Comment: IMO a better recommendation is `my $string; $string = 'Hello!' if 0;`